# How to display loading screen in Blackberry

Tags: java, blackberry, xml-parsing, blackberry-simulator

I have a problem with Blackberry.

```
        // Stream connection
        streamConnection = (StreamConnection) Connector
                .open(_url);
        // Document Builder Factory
        DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                .newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        docBuilder.isValidating();
        // Parsing inputStream
        doc = docBuilder.parse(streamConnection.openInputStream());
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("*");
```

I want to display Loading Dialog until above the task parser is complete. Because after finished task XML parser, i have to use it for display on screen.

So, how to display Loading dialog until Parser XML is complete?
Please help me !
Thanks you very much!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: hello following answer is useful to you or not.Let me know please..

Comment: if you really need answer then improve your accept ratio...

Comment: In fact, my application has many times connect to server and parser XML...
I tried your way but i don't implement all case. 


When I run app, I pushScreen and I run getArtistInfor method in Constuctor of Screen.
I understood your solution but I need the solution for all my cases !

Comment: I want to upload my source but I can't use " Post your answer"...@@

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hi this is pretty much easy task

following link redirect you how to implement Please wait screen 
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Sample-quot-Please-Wait-quot-screen-part-1/ta-p/493808 
download that .zip file

Next take small logic into your application firs take all your parsing concept into a **Thread**

for example i am taking xml parser demo and i will convert according to our requirement

```
private class Connection extends Thread{
        Vector nodes_vect=new Vector();
        Vector elements_vect=new Vector();
        public Connection(){
            super();
        }

        public void run(){
            // define variables later used for parsing
            Document doc;
            StreamConnection conn;

            try{
                //providing the location of the XML file,
                //your address might be different
                conn=(StreamConnection)Connector.open
                  ("http://localhost:8000/content/test.xml;deviceside=true");//  http://localhost:8000/content/test.xml
                //next few lines creates variables to open a
                //stream, parse it, collect XML data and
                //extract the data which is required.
                //In this case they are elements,
                //node and the values of an element
                DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory
                  = DocumentBuilderFactory. newInstance(); 
                DocumentBuilder docBuilder
                  = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                docBuilder.isValidating();
                doc = docBuilder.parse(conn.openInputStream());
                doc.getDocumentElement ().normalize ();
                NodeList list=doc.getElementsByTagName("*");
                _node=new String();
                _element = new String();
                //this "for" loop is used to parse through the
                //XML document and extract all elements and their
                //value, so they can be displayed on the device

                for (int i=0;i<list.getLength();i++){
                    Node value=list.item(i).
                      getChildNodes().item(0);
                    _node=list.item(i).getNodeName();
                    _element=value.getNodeValue();
                  nodes_vect.addElement(_node);
                  elements_vect.addElement(_element);
                   if(i==list.getLength()-1){


                       pushingToNextScreen(nodes_vect, elements_vect);//after last element it will 
                   }
                }//end for
            }//end try
            //will catch any exception thrown by the XML parser
            catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println(e.toString());
            }
        }//end connection function
    }// end connection class
}//end XML_Parsing_Sample
```

you can call this from any where

```
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.microedition.io.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.*;
import net.rim.device.api.system.*;
import net.rim.device.api.xml.parsers.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import org.xml.sax.*;

class XML_Parsing_Sample extends UiApplication{
    //creating a member variable for the MainScreen
    MainScreen _screen= new MainScreen();
    //string variables to store the values of the XML document
    String _node,_element;
    Connection _connectionthread;

    public static void main(String arg[]){
        XML_Parsing_Sample application = new XML_Parsing_Sample();
        //create a new instance of the application
        //and start the application on the event thread
        application.enterEventDispatcher();
    }

    public XML_Parsing_Sample() {

        UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new LoadingScreen());
            }
        });


       // pushScreen(_screen); // creating a screen
        //creating a connection thread to run in the background
        _connectionthread = new Connection();
        _connectionthread.start();//starting the thread operation
    }

    public void pushingToNextScreen(final Vector node,final Vector elem){
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                 UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen());
                 UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new datascreen(node, elem));//after last element it will call mainscreen constructer
            }
        });
    }

  class datascreen extends MainScreen
  {
      public datascreen(Vector node,Vector elem) {
        //you can write your logic and design with data(vectors contain all data)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your support, but How can I show "Loading..." Dialog when parser process is Start and close Dialog when parser is finished?

Comment: when i==list.getLength()-1 we can assume this is last element then we can call the one function pushingToNextScreen() inside that close that loading screen and push into new screen

Answer (score 0):

Put a `Screen` instance (`PopupScreen`) on the display stack before start processing 'XML Parsing' module, and upon completion remove that screen from display stack. You may need to override some key press event on that screen that satisfy your need, e.g. do nothing on back button press. And add your customize dialog text / animation on that screen.

Comment: Ok. But How can I known when the process XML parsing is finished?

Comment: if your parsing code isn't run on a different thread then usually after the execution of the last line of the parsing code module, XML parsing is done.. and it's upon you :). Better you finish the parsing task first successfully and then try to add the loading screen.

Comment: After completion of XML parsing you have to pop the "POPUP Screen", Means you push the "POPUP Screen" before start the XML Paring and popups Before push the New screen;

Answer (score 0):

find the application (PleaseWait.zip) in below link to show the please wait.

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/problem-in-gaugfield-show-urgent/td-p/964925